# Why doesn't the Digest gem show all the class as constants?

Tags: ruby, hash

I am using the digest module for some task.

As always, [ruby-doc](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest.html) has a very nice documentation.

When I want to get the classes from a module or class:

```
module A
    class B end
    C = Class.new(B)
    D ||= 1
end
A.const_set(:E, Math::E)

p A.constants                                                  # => [:B, :C, :D, :E]
p A.constants.select { |x| A.const_get(x).kind_of?(Class) }    # => [:B, :C]
```

But in Digest module, something ridiculous is happening:

```
require 'digest'      # => true

p Digest.constants    # => [:Class, :Base, :REQUIRE_MUTEX, :Instance]
p Digest::SHA1        # => Digest::SHA1
p Digest.constants    # => [:Class, :Base, :SHA1, :REQUIRE_MUTEX, :Instance]
p Digest::SHA2        # => Digest::SHA2
p Digest.constants    # => [:Class, :SHA2, :Base, :SHA1, :SHA256, :REQUIRE_MUTEX, :SHA512, :SHA384, :Instance]
```

As you can see the constant method doesn't return `SHA1` class (on line 2). Then when I write `Digest::SHA1` the program loads up the `SHA1` class. Then when you run call the `constants` method again, it returns the `SHA1` in the array.

What's going on here? Is there a way not to load all the classes in my program the same way? Is this an efficient design?

Comment: That's a lot of questions. Can you focus your post? What is it that you're actually asking?

Comment: Also it was a pleasant surprise to see `[hash]` tag used appropriately. I _almost_ auto-removed it :)

Comment: The question is that first of all, there's no `SHA1` constant in the `Digest` module (as `constants` method tells), but when you type `Digest::SHA1` it loads up `SHA1` class. How can I do the same for my programs?

Comment: Never mind, I have added added only `ruby` and `digest` in the tags. It automatically selects `hash` instead of `digest`...

Comment: "How can I do the same for my programs' - one word, `const_missing`. This is how rails does it, for example.

Comment: Actually I think loading classes like this might have to do with `Module#autoload`?

Comment: Ah yes, that one looks useful too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197303/discussion-between-s-goswami-and-sergio-tulentsev).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic is in the `const_missing` singleton method in the Digest module. @knugje has pointed out a very useful link in his answer which makes in clearer.

ri documentation about `const_missing` says:

> Invoked when a reference is made to an undefined constant in mod

So here's the trick:

```
module X
    def self.const_missing(name)
        name
    end
end

p X.constants        # => []
p X::Y               # => :Y
p X.constants        # => []
```

So the code doesn't define the constant in the module. So we can use a fairly simple trick:

```
module X
    define_singleton_method(:const_missing) { |n| const_set(n, n.id2name) }
end

p X.constants      # => []
p X::Y             # => "Y"
p X::Z             # => "Z"
p X.constants      # => [:Y, :Z]
p X::Z             # "Z"
```

That's how `const_missing` is used here. But Instead of `const_set`, what digest does is loading up a file with the name and do some exception handling and checking if the constants exist on the file.

Personally speaking, this may create confusion. For example, when you have no document to offline and online documents, you can't just simply run `Digest.constants` to list the available constants.

As knugie pointed out, you can read about the `const_missing` implementation in the Digest module [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/5ad2dfd8dce00f9fb4908adc786f12baaaf2b273/ext/digest/lib/digest.rb#L8-L25).

Answer (score 2):

In the case of `Digest`, this behaviour is intentional. Depending on the hashing algorithm, different libraries are required. This is counterintuitive, but it's also expected behaviour as you can see here: [https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/ext/digest/lib/digest.rb#L8-L25](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/5ad2dfd8dce00f9fb4908adc786f12baaaf2b273/ext/digest/lib/digest.rb#L8-L25).

To change that, Ruby Core would need according adoption.
I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: It was quite confusing to figure out what they were actually doing! Thanks for your answer!